# Checkbox not displaying

Tags: css, html

I am trying to integrate an HTML 5 `required` checkbox into a form:

```html
<p>
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" required name="terms"> By submitting you agree to the processing of your data for the purpose of processing your request/booking.
  <br>
  <a href="/en/datenschutz.php" target="_blank">
    <u>Privacy  Policy</u>
  </a>
</p>
```

It is not displaying in a single browser. I haven't had this problem with other sites before, this site is running Bootstrap v2.2.2.

I found some possible solution with labels which didn't work.

Comment: Can't reproduce, it's showing up fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Stephen Leppik. I messed up in presentation and handling of my question and created confusion. NEWBIE here. It's solved!

Comment: This may look as a benign mistake but I discovered this question and it lead me to the solution which in my case was a faulty framework dependency which "leaked" a CSS rule hiding the checkbox. So your question made me look in this direction and find the actual error. So thank you - it saved me a ton of time barking up the wrong trees. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Style.css file has this rule:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Delete it and you will see your checkbox.

If you need that rule for whatever reason and you only want to override it for this particular checkbox, then you'll have to add another CSS rule to override it. Obviously, adding an inline style will do the job, but it might be not the best way to go:

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" required name="terms" style="display: inline-block;">
```

Comment: What is your reason for assuming this?

Comment: @SirExotic Assuming what? I assumed nothing. If you look at the question's history, the OP had a link to the website. If you check the code for the website, you'll see the CSS rule in the Style.css file. Then the question was edited and the link to the website removed, but that's not my fault, is it? Of course, people come glance quickly and downvote without bothering themselves to actually understand what's going on. Oh well, they're just being people :).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm new here, next time I'll prepare my questions more thorougly and I will read up on the guidelines here. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies then, I just saw it. Strange that OP removed the link, that's only going to bring confusion..

Comment: No problem, @Cloudburst. Learning is always positive. We welcome you :)

Comment: @SirExotic Apology accepted :). At least you kindly added a comment for me to know what's going on. The other downvoters didn't bother, and their downvotes will stay with an accepted answer, so ironic :).

Comment: Thanks for quick help and the nice welcome to both of you! Again, sorry for the confusion :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your style.css might contain the appearance css property. This is used to display an element using platform-native styling, based on the operating system's theme. Look up : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

your code might contain a css  rule such as:

```css
input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

if you wanna keep this property and change the checkbox specifically then use :

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    appearance: checkbox !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both css. 
But here 
**style="display: inline-block;"**
inside input type are override display: none;

```css
input.checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
}

/*input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline-block;
}*/
```

```html
<p>
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" required name="terms">By submitting you agree to the processing of your data for the purpose of processing your request/booking.
</p>

<a href="/en/datenschutz.php" target="_blank">
  <u>Privacy  Policy</u>
</a>
```